# Displaying concatenated sqldata

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display data from `multiple rows in sql` in a single table box. 
in the format of:

```
"MovieTitle" "movieReleaseYear" "directorName"

The Matrix      1999             Andy Wachowski, Lana Wachowski
```

where `Andy Wachowski and Lana Wachowski` comes from different rows but are gathered with `group_concat`

I have no problem getting them in phpmyadmin but i don't know how to display it in php.

I have this:

```
$sql="SELECT 725G54_5_movies.MovieTitle, 725G54_5_movies.movieProductionYear,      GROUP_CONCAT( 725G54_5_director.directorName ) 
                    FROM 725G54_5_movies
                    JOIN 725G54_5_directed ON 725G54_5_movies.MovieID = 725G54_5_directed.movieID
                    JOIN 725G54_5_director ON 725G54_5_directed.directorID = 725G54_5_director.directorID
                    GROUP BY 725G54_5_movies.MovieTitle
                    ORDER BY $order ASC";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);  

                //Presentation av kontakterna via while-sats till ett formulär
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                echo "<tr>
                <td>"; echo $rows['MovieTitle']; echo "</td>
                <td>";  echo $rows['movieProductionYear']; echo "</td>
                <td>"; 
                    while($director=mysql_fetch_array($rows['directorName'])){ echo $director; }; 
                    echo"</td>
                </tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Group Concat has already concatenate the name of the directors, so you don't need to iterate  on `$rows['directorName']` .This part in your code id wrong because `$rows` is a row from the query result and `$rows['director']` is a value from this row, you can't iterate on a value.

```
 $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 725G54_5_director.directorName ) AS directorNames ..."

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['MovieTitle'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rows['movieProductionYear'] . "</td>"
                echo "<td>" . $rows['directorNames'] . "</td>" 
                echo"</tr>";
}
```

You use `GROUP BY 725G54_5_movies.MovieTitle` so `directorNames` field will be the result of all `directorName` concatenated for this Movie.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial bit of information is that you need to alias your GROUP_CONCAT so that you can access this in the array. I would also use a Heredoc when outputting blocks of html for readability:

```
$sql=
"SELECT
    725G54_5_movies.MovieTitle,
    725G54_5_movies.movieProductionYear,
    GROUP_CONCAT(725G54_5_director.directorName) directorNames
FROM
    725G54_5_movies
    JOIN
    725G54_5_directed
    ON 725G54_5_movies.MovieID = 725G54_5_directed.movieID
    JOIN
    725G54_5_director
    ON 725G54_5_directed.directorID = 725G54_5_director.directorID
GROUP BY
    725G54_5_movies.MovieTitle
ORDER BY
    $order ASC";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

//Presentation av kontakterna via while-sats till ett formulär
echo "<table>";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo <<<HTML
        <tr>
            <td>{$rows['MovieTitle']}</td>
            <td>{$rows['movieProductionYear']}</td>
            <td>{$rows['directorNames']}</td>
        </tr>
HTML;
}
echo "</table>";
```